# How can I convert a list type to a numeric type in Python

Tags: python, list, types, numeric

I have a external file that is a single column of floating point numbers ( want to be able to expand it to have multiple columns in the future). I want to import it into an array. The file is a cvs file but it just as well could be a txt file.

I am using:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("e=0.6.csv"))
table = []
for row in reader:
    values = []    
    for col in row: 
        values.append(float(col))
    table.aapend(values)
```

The result is a list `[[1.0], [0.98], ......]`
I want to convert the List to an array of numbers `(1.0, 0.98, ...)`
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
reader = csv.reader(open("e=0.6.csv"))
table = tuple(float(col) for row in reader for col in row)
```

Comment: You don't need the square brackets here: you can pass a generator expression as the only argument to `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you make a new list called values? Why not append to table instead? i.e.

```
reader = csv.reader(open("e=0.6.csv"))
table = []
for row in reader: 
    for col in row: 
        table.append(float(col))
```

Answer (score 1):

`(1.0, 0.98, ...)` is a *tuple*.  Here's one way to make a tuple from that:

```
>>> l = [[1.0], [0.98]]
>>> tuple(i[0] for i in l)
(1.0, 0.97999999999999998)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, I'd skip this step and just do something like:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("e=0.6.csv"))

table = [float(col) for col in row for row in reader]
```

However if you wanted to go with your original answer you can do:

Use the [map method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> l = [[1.0], [0.98], [3.0]]
>>> map(lambda x: x[0], l)
[1.0, 0.97999999999999998, 3.0]
```

Or list comprehension:

```
>>> [e for subl in l for e in subl]
[1.0, 0.97999999999999998, 3.0]
```

In either case, you can convert the list returned into a tuple by just doing `tuple(result)`

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = csv.reader(open("e=0.6.csv"))
table = []
for row in reader:
    for col in row: 
        table.aapend(float(col))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [[0.1], [0.2], [0.3]]
>>> [x[0] for x in l]
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

Or the map function:

```
>>> map(lambda x:x[0], l)
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

Or the reduce function:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, l, [])
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

Or a generator:

```
>>> (x[0] for x in l)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004e00f0>
```

Or just store your numbers directly in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're using `csv.reader` in this case. You said yourself that it wasn't really a csv! Just do either:

```
map(float, open("e=0.6.csv").readlines())
```

or

```
[float(x) for x in open("e=0.6.csv").readlines()]
```